# How to resolve gradle tls connection after upgrading from 5.4 to 6.8.3?

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, java-11

I upgrade the projects Gradle version from 5.4.1 to 6.8.3 and have changed the custom repository to https.

I had a similar issue with maven but after mirroring has been solved. I can build the project without anyproblem with gradle 5.4.1 but when I upgrade the gradle to 6.8.3 then I got the following error:

```
        The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used.
     See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                          > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: There is not enough information about the problem. we need comprehensive information about the project. you are using Docker and containers. However, you didn't put any information about that. run-time env is important, 32bit or 64bit system or software is important, JRE, JDK how you containerize is important. and so. please provide as much information as you can. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

You get this message when the JRE is missing a certificate. I think you are going to have to install your company's certificate in the docker image's JRE

Your Dockerfile will need to do something like:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine

// my-company.crt is your company's certificate
COPY my-company.crt my-company.crt

RUN keytool -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias my-alias -file my-company.crt
```

Comment: curiously with  `jdk8`  I am having still the same issue. But with JDK 11 it works

Comment: I'm assuming that's a different docker image, have you installed the certificate in both images?

Comment: Yes, I did the same steps. The only difference is the jdk8 image does not run `RUN keytool -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias begoroot -file my-company.crt` with `-cacerts`  flags. I ran without `-cacerts`.

Comment: I think with java 8 you'll need to do `-file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` instead of `-cacerts`

Answer (score 3):

The following solution worked for me. I just disabled TLS

In Repositories section of your gradle:

Replace `mavenCentral()` with

```
maven { 
    url = "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"
    allowInsecureProtocol = true
}
```

and `jcenter()` with

```
maven { 
    url = "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
    allowInsecureProtocol = true
}
```

and for any other repositories just use the url with HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS and make sure to set `allowInsecureProtocol = true`

Comment: And I need to point out that if you are behind a network firewall like me and you're using windows and need to connect to internet through a proxy, make sure to use a software that tunnels your whole traffic through that proxy like Proxifier

Comment: Does not work here

Comment: It doesn;t work

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was a result of my internet service provider using a custom CA certificate to intercept and filter my SSL traffic.

Once I connected to the internet with a proper CA certificate chain the build completed without error.

Notes:

1. This error can be a result of any SSL certificate / CA issue on you internet connection.
2. Once the build completes all is good until the build needs to download  a new gradle version.